# Repeatedly check login status of the user on facebook using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-login

I want to repeatedly check users login status on facebook.
I am using facebook javascript SDK for implementing login functionality.
Now if users logged out from anywhere, he should not be able to read that particular post. This means he can only access that post only if he is logged in. So i want to make sure that, at periodic interval whether the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with [`FB.Event.subscribe()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.3), using both: `auth.authResponseChange` and `auth.statusChange` events. And see if these are getting invoked when the user state changes automatically.

Otherwise, you could probably call [`FB.getLoginStatus()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) to check the user status. Also note the section about [roundtrips](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/#servers).

NOTE: I wouldn't make this based on interval but instead on user interaction with the page. Otherwise, you may end up calling Facebook servers too aggressively for no reason.